# Python Pandas Dataframe to calculate the selected columns' mean values for each category and return as a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are multiple categories in Doc_type column, I want to calculate the mean values using selected columns for each category and add the category back into a dataframe. Instead of having all records from the original DataFrame, I want to only have one row for each category contains the mean values for selected columns in a dataframe

```
for name in sample.Doc_type.unique():
    df_mean = sample[sample.Doc_type == name][
        [
            "total_tokens_per_doc",
            "valid_token_percentage",
            "special_chars_percentage",
            "numeric_values_percentage",
        ]
    ].median()
    print(df_mean)
```

```
Results:
total_tokens_per_doc         64.000000
valid_token_percentage        0.590551
special_chars_percentage      0.122449
numeric_values_percentage     0.340000
dtype: float64
total_tokens_per_doc         69.000000
valid_token_percentage        0.595376
special_chars_percentage      0.107143
numeric_values_percentage     0.316327
dtype: float64
total_tokens_per_doc         48.000000
valid_token_percentage        0.656250
special_chars_percentage      0.133333
numeric_values_percentage     0.250000
dtype: float64
total_tokens_per_doc         37.000000
valid_token_percentage        0.651685
special_chars_percentage      0.142857
numeric_values_percentage     0.242424
dtype: float64
total_tokens_per_doc         2.0
valid_token_percentage       0.5
special_chars_percentage     0.0
numeric_values_percentage    0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html):

```py
columns = ['Doc_type',
           "total_tokens_per_doc",
           "valid_token_percentage",
           "special_chars_percentage",
           "numeric_values_percentage"]

df_mean = sample[columns].groupby('Doc_type').median()

# to get the groupby variable as a column rather than an index:
df_mean.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: One follow up question, how to convert Doc_type into a column instead of using as a groupby filter. Done by adding reset.index().

Comment: Thanks @one_random_python_learner. I added your follow-up solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume here is your Sample data:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[4,5,6,7], 'c':[8,9,7,6]})
```

Then mean values for selected column:

```
sample[['a','b']].mean()
```

Sample Output:

```
a    2.5
b    5.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: From the sample data you have, let's say you have another column as categoy aa,bb,cc,dd. And we want to find the mean values of columns [['a','b']] for each category. Final step making the sample output as a dataframe object having column names a,b,category and values for each column(s).